# Algorithm for sentence analysis and tokenization

Tags: c#, nlp

I need to analyze a document and compile statistics as to how many times each a sequence of words is used (so the analysis is not on single words but of batch of recurring words).  I read that compression algorithms do something similar to what I want - creating dictionaries of blocks of text with a piece of information reporting its frequency.
It should be something similar to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Patterns.aspx
Do you have anything written in C#?

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to implement.

1. Use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)(a member function of string class) to split the string into words. (you can use the delimiters in the codeproject url).
2. A forloop to enumerate all the n-gram out and use `Dictionary<string, int>` to get the count.